# jQuery Mobile listview border radius and border

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, border, css

If I set a border radius and a border for the thumbnail in a listview, it seems to treat the border as part of the picture like this:

[image]

The CSS override rule I'm using is this:

```
.ui-li-thumb {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 8px;
    border: 2px solid #333 !important;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
```

How do I make it so the image has the border-radius too, so it doesn't overlap its border?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to expand on my comment above and show you exactly how you could dynamically change change the images into background images using JavaScript:

JavaScript:

```
$('li').each(function(index) {

    // Find thumbnail image
    var thumb = $(this).find('img');  

    // Get the src
    var thumbsrc = thumb.attr('src');

    // Insert a span (absolutely positioned using below css)
    thumb.after('<span class="thumbnail" />');

    // Apply our thumbnail as a background image to the span
    $(this).find('span.thumbnail').css("background-image", 'url(' + thumbsrc + ')'); 

    // remove thumbnail image
    $(this).find('img').remove();
});
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
    width:18px;
    height: 16px;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left:10px; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}​
```

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/x54A6/1/

Comment: This works if you change the final line of the JS to `thumb.hide();` (otherwise the text on the right is moved under the image). Thanks :)

Comment: Cool, yeah likely to be a bit different depending on your individual setup.

Answer (score 3):

You can't currently apply border radius' to images, which really sucks. What you would have to do is set it as a background for a div with a border radius for it to work.

Comment: Not sure how well it will work with jQuery Mobiles markup, but you could even do it dynamically. Search for the images in the DOM, remove them and then reapply them as a background image to the closest span using jQuery.